# Sets of measure zero in uncountable product spaces?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have an uncountable number of probability spaces $\Pi_i = (\Omega_i, B_i,\mu_i)$ indexed by $i \in [0,1]$, where $\Omega_i$ is the base set, $B_i$ is a collection of Borel-measurable  sets, and $\mu_i: B_i \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is a measure.

I can define a measure $\mu$ on the product space $\times_{i \in [0,1]} \Pi_i$ such that $\mu(S \times  (\times_{j \neq i} \Omega_i)) = \mu_i(S)$ for any $S \in B_i$.

Inside each $\Pi_i$, I have a subset $S_i \subset \Omega_i$ such that $\mu_i(S_i = 0)$.  Let $\mathcal{I} \subset [0,1]$ be a subset of $[0,1]$ such that $\mu( (\times_{i \in \mathcal{I}} S_i) \times (\times_{i \not \in \mathcal{I}} \Omega_i )) > 0$. I want to show that either this can never happen, or that it happens only if $\mathcal{I}$ has Lebesgue-measure greater than zero.  I have the following argument, but  I'm not sure it is valid:

1. Let $T_i = \Omega_i - S_i$. Then $\mu_i(T_i) = 1$.
2. Write $\Omega -  (\times_{i \in \mathcal{I}} S_i) \times (\times_{i \not \in \mathcal{I}} \Omega_i ) =\cup_{i \in [0,1]} T_i \times (\times_{j \neq i} \Omega_j)$
3. Write $\mu( (\times_{i \in \mathcal{I}} S_i) \times (\times_{i \not \in \mathcal{I}} \Omega_i )) =  1-  \mu(\cup_{i \in [0,1]} T_i \times (\times_{j \neq i} \Omega_j))$
4. We can write $1 - \mu(\cup_{i \in [0,1]} T_i \times (\times_{j \neq i} \Omega_j)) 1 - \int_{0}^{1} \mu_i(T_i) di = 0$, where the first equality comes from the definition of the measure $\mu$ on the product  space. **I think taking the measure of an uncountable union is the questionable step  here**.

This is an argument that $(\times_{i \in \mathcal{I}} S_i) \times (\times_{i \not \in \mathcal{I}} \Omega_i )$  has measure zero. As I said, I'm not sure it is valid.

Comment: This needs an edit there's inconsistency in the definitions. You define $S_i$ with measure zero and then don't use it and you never define $A_i$ (I suppose $S_i=A_i$?). If $S_i=A_i$ then it makes no sense because $\times_{i\in \mathcal{I}} A_i \subseteq A_1 \times (\times_{i\not = 1} \Omega_i)$ which is of measure zero, so how can it be of positive measure? Also you mentioned an argument in the end but I don't see any.

Comment: Thanks, I added the edits, and pointed out where I think the argument is questionable